# How to rename a file with % in the file name?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have written a batch script to rename files with prefix, but it is not renaming the files with `%` as part of the name. Other files are renamed fine.

For example for renaming `abc 10% discount.doc` to `1234_abc 10% discount.doc` my batch script is:

```
rename "abc 10% discount.doc" "1234_abc 10% discount.doc"
```

How to make this work?

Comment: Double the percent symbols.

Comment: `%` is a shell metachar. if you want a literal `%`, then it has to be `%%` on the command-line.

Comment: @MarcB Doubling percents works only in batch files, not on the command line

Answer (score 1):

A % defines a variable. To use the sign itself in a string simply write %%.